# Preprocessor macro: Missing parenthesis

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and trying to write a preprocessor macro, which will check at compile-time if a VERSION is a valid BCD number:

```
#define VERSION (uint8)0x01u

#if ((VERSION > 0x99u) || ((VERSION & 0x0Fu) > 0x09u))
#error "Invalid version"
#endif
```

But for some reason VS2013 shows the following message:

```
error C1012: unmatched parenthesis : missing ')'
```

I've checked my parenthesis a few times - but it looks right to me. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor doesn't understand types, so this cannot work. Assuming `uint8` is not a macro, this will expand to

```
#if (((0)0x01u > 0x99u) || (((0)0x01u & 0x0Fu) > 0x09u))
```

because all identifiers that are left after macro replacement are replaced by zero. This clearly has syntax errors. The error message you're getting seems misleading to me, but the fact that you're getting an error message at all is appropriate.

Do you really need `VERSION` to have type `uint8`? If not, you can simply remove the cast.

If you do need to have it as type `uint8`, you need to write the expression in such a way that it remains valid even if it gets replaced by `0`, such as `((uint8)+0x01u)`.

Comment: In this case the uint8 cast is 100% superfluous, since the `(uint8)0x01u` will get immediately integer promoted to type `int` when used in the expression. And then balancing against the right operand of the > operator will promote it further, to be of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: Oh, ok - I see: Thank you! In fact the `(uint8)0x01u` part is legacy code which I haven't written by myself - just the macro to evaluate the version.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot define macros as `#define VERSION (uint8)0x01u`

define it as'

```
#define VERSION 0x01u
```